# Get SelectedValue at SelectedIndex in DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, postback

Is this possible? I programatically change the selected index when a certain event is fired using this code:

```
DropDownList.SelectedIndex = DropDownList.SelectedIndex + 1
```

Now I want to update a corresponding textbox with the text that is in the new SelectedIndex of the DropDownList via postback.

What's the easiest way to do this?

---

I know how I can do this in javascript.... I was just wondering if i could do this in the VB code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextBox.Text = DropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

Read more about [ListControl.SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you serious thats all i need? I don't need to somehow pass the selectedIndex with it?

Comment: I think so. You could also do `DropDownList.Items[DropDownList.SelectedIndex]`

Comment: That's right -- you don't need the SelectedIndex to get the text.