# Drop down's selected Index doesn't match the position of the displayed selected element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list and an add button. When the add button is clicked, the selected item from the dropdown is supposed to be added to a database.  However the selectedIndex value used in the function called by the add button is wrong.  It doesn't match the actual index of the currently selected item (most of the time.)

Here is the dropdown and the button:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlNewCreature" AutoPostBack = "false" DataMember="0"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnAddCreature" runat="server" Text="Add" onClick="AddCreature"/>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                     
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    if (ddParent1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        if (ddBaby.Items.Count == 0)
        {
        loadCreatureLists(true, true);
        }
        else
        {
        loadCreatureLists(true, false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (ddBaby.Items.Count == 0)
        {
        loadCreatureLists(false, true);
        }
    }
    }
}


protected void loadCreatureLists(Boolean loadParents, Boolean loadOffspring )
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Drin"].ConnectionString);
    string sSql = "select creature, element1, element2 from dbo.tinycastlecreatures order by creature";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
    conn.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
        newItem.Text = reader["creature"].ToString();
        newItem.Value = normalizeElementOrder(reader["element1"].ToString(),reader["element2"].ToString());
        if (loadParents && !chkMine.Checked)
        {

        ddParent1.Items.Add(newItem);
        ddParent2.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
        if (loadOffspring)
        {
        ddBaby.Items.Add(newItem);
        ddlNewCreature.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err) { }
    finally { if (!loadParents || !chkMine.Checked) { conn.Close(); } }
}

protected void AddCreature(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int indx = ddlNewCreature.SelectedIndex;
    string sCreature = ddlNewCreature.Items[indx].Text.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < ddlNewCreature.Items.Count; i++ )
    {
    sCreature = ddlNewCreature.Items[i].Text.ToString();
    }
    ddlNewCreature.SelectedIndex = 0;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Drin"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string sSql = "[dbo].[tinycastle_add_user_creature] '";
    sSql += sCreature;
    sSql += "','deb'"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sCreature = ddlNewCreature.Items[indx].Text.ToString();
    sqlMineSource.DataBind();
    gridMine.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: By the way, the only purpose of the for loop in the AddCreature procedure was so that I could inspect through debug tools what was actually in the dropdown list. Watching it execute, the item visibly shown as selected had an index of around 70 while the value of indx was normally 5.

Comment: Can you check the index at selectedindex changed event?

Comment: It is also "5" or in otherwords it is the wrong value. So here is what I think is happening.  Since I'm trying to select an item that is way down the list, I am resting the mouse briefly on a higher item while I scroll to find the one I want.  I think this is triggering the select change.  What I don't understand is why, by the time I've finally found the item I want, and clicked over to the add button, why the app hasn't caught up and set the select index to the value I picked last...the one that is displaying. Or more relevantly...how do I ensure it uses the last selection and not the first?

Comment: This idea that its using the wrong index of potentially several selectedindex matches with the observed behavior that I don't have the problem when picking an option that is at the top of the list.

Comment: Or not.  When I let the application keep running it turns out that it is only firing OnSelectedIndexChanged once.

Comment: I decided to change the way the dropdown list was populated, to use a datasource instead.  For some reason that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

B.Yaylaci's suggestion on checking the `SelectedIndex` in the dropdown's changed event is on the right track to find out why (when? :)) the index isn't matching up with what you expect, I think. 
Also, it'd be much easier (and more-accurate) to use the `SelectedValue` property if all you need is the text in the dropdown.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399747

Comment: Good point.  Although actually it appears to be the SelectedItem property that gets the displayed text.  SelectedValue gets the hidden Value, which in my case happens to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I circumvented the problem by ripping out the way the various drop down lists were populated, and binding them to a SQLDataStore instead.  I don't know why that helped, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Use ddlNewCreature.SelectedValue this will fix your problem." SelectedValue " give you the correct index value for the selected DropDownList. This worked for me.